# Responsive Alignment CSS

Tags: css

So I'm either missing something or misunderstanding how this should work, and I'm near my wit's end.

I would like to have four columns. Each column will have an image and a div containing text. The image should fill the width of the column with any overflow hidden so that the entire height does not exceed 600px. The wrapper should be centered horizontally and everything should be responsive, as I will delete the right column depending on screen size.

My problems... when all four columns are displayed, my text divs are not as wide as the images. When I kill #column4, the text divs are the same width as the images, but then I can't center the wrapper on the page. And the image in #column1, at some screen widths, won't hide the overflow of the image, so part of it "sticks out" so that he column is taller than the others. *sigh* I'm obviously self-taught... poorly.

I've tried killing the float and changing the display, but each display option gives me odd vertical spacing.

Edited to include an image of all four columns. First, and most irritating, is that I cannot get the wrapper div centered on the page. Also, note the images and text boxes are different widths. (However, when the page is narrower and column4 is hidden, then the widths are the same.) Finally, I would like the image to fill the available space vertically (65% and 75% of the column) with the text divs to fill the remainder so that all columns are the same height.

[CSS Fail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cr2QZ.jpg)

```css
  #dcwrapper {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  height: 600px;
  margin: 10px 5%;
  position: relative;
}

.column {
  width: 24%;
  margin-right: 1%;
  float: left;
}

#text1 {
  height: 35%;
  width: 100%;
}

#text2 {
  height: 25%;
  width: 100%;
}

#text3 {
  height: 25%;
  width: 100%;
}

#text4 {
  height: 35%;
  width: 100%;
}

#image1 img {
  max-height: 385px;
  max-width: 295px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#image2 img {
  max-height: 445px;
  max-width: 295px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#image3 img {
  max-height: 445px;
  max-width: 295px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#image4 img {
  max-height: 385px;
  max-width: 295px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.txt {
  border: solid 2px #799048;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 5px;
}


.image65{
    height:65%;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.image75{
    height:75%;
    overflow:hidden;
}

/* HIDE COLUMNS AT WIDTHS */

@media only screen and (max-width: 1250px) {
    #column4 {
      display: none;
    }
    #image1 img {
      max-width: 100%;
    }
    #image2 img {
      max-width: 100%;
    }
    #image3 img {
      max-width: 100%;
    }
    #image4 img {
      max-width: 100%;
    }
  }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="column1" class="column">
    <div id="text1" class="txt">
      These are our hours.
    </div>
    <!--end text1-->

    <div id="image1" class="image65">
      <img src="1a.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--end column1-->

  <div id="column2" class="column">
    <div id="image2" class="image75">
      <img src="2a.jpg" />
    </div>

    <div id="text2" class="txt">
      We have a lot of different products now.
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--end column2-->

  <div id="column3" class="column">
    <div id="text3" class="txt">
      Yo, make an appointment!
    </div>

    <div id="image3" class="image75">
      <img src="3a.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--end column3-->

  <div id="column4" class="column">
    <div id="image4" class="image65">
      <img src="4a.jpg" />
    </div>

    <div id="text4" class="txt">
      Lookey what's new
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--end column4-->
</div>
<!--end wrapper-->
```

Comment: You have a missing closing bracket after the styles for #column4 in the media query.

Comment: Thanks... didn't copy it over properly. Fixed. :)

Comment: So that's not the cause of the problem you're having? Can you show a better example then (with real images) because I can't tell from the snippet what's wrong.

Comment: Absolutely. Image attached.

Comment: So I just killed the max-width from all of the image classes and the width in the media query and that has fixed my image issues. Now all I need to figure out is how to center the wrapper. Looking at it, it appears as though even though my div is "display:none;" the wrapper is still holding a place for it. Is there another way to hide a div for media queries?

Comment: Nevermind... that's not it. It's all floated left.